# Is there a word for online-only jerks?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Is there a word, phrase or urban saying for people who appears polite and reasonable in real life, but is rude and trolling everything on the internet?

Comment: I thought that's what a "troll" was – see [Definition #9 here](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/troll) and [Definition #3 here](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/troll), although I suppose that term doesn't necessarily imply the person is "polite and reasonable in real life".

Comment: Maybe so, but I've never imagined *troll* implying that the user is polite or reasonable in real life.

Comment: @snailboat: I was just thinking (and typing) the same thing :^) I'm not sure we'll get a word for a person who is polite offline but plays the troll online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer that comes to mind is, unfortunately, rather crude:

- [*Internet asshole*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Internet%20Asshole) is a slang term.  It's probable that not everyone knows this term, but it's pretty much self-explanatory (a person who is an asshole on the internet).

To describe the phenomenon in general and not a specific person, you can talk about the [online disinhibition effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_disinhibition_effect).  The webcomic Penny Arcade also popularized a term for this effect, though it is again rather crude--you may see people refer to it by the name [G.I.F.T.](http://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2004/03/19)